# remove elements from list if it cannot be converted into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list `l` and I want to remove all the elements that cannot be converted into float.

```
l = ['348.00 ', '348.00 ', '(348.00) ', '0.00 ', 'USD ']
```

This list is extracted from an invoice data and I want to convert all numbers into float for further calculation and hence, words should be removed.

Expected output:

```
l = [348.00, 348.00, 0.00]
```

Comment: @AbbasEbadian That will produce an empty list for the above input.

Comment: Can you expand it?  I am not comfortable with comprehensions

Comment: @AbbasEbadian - You should add that as an answer to the question if you think it solves the problem. (it doesn't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a bit heavy on the utils for an easy task, but the following will work:

```
def floatify(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

l = ['348.00 ', '348.00 ', '(348.00) ', '0.00 ', 'USD ']
l[:] = filter(float.__instancecheck__, map(floatify, l))
l
# [348.0, 348.0, 0.0]
```

Or more straightforward, with a simple loop:

```
l = ['348.00 ', '348.00 ', '(348.00) ', '0.00 ', 'USD ']

new_l = []
for s in l:
    try:
        new_l.append(float(s))
    except ValueError:
        pass
l[:] = new_l
```